# Повернуть ПЛАВНО по клику элемент на 180 градусов на Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, анимация

Нужно что бы элемент по первому клику **плавно** поворачивался на 180 градусов, по второму, возвращался к начальному состоянию. Здесь как-то задействуется метод .toggle(), но я пока не нашел решение.

Comment: `.toggleClass` скорее

Comment: Да это понятно, но я хочу это сделать плавно

Comment: раз понятно это, то не понятно что мешает сделать это плавно ... вот если бы это было непонятно, тогда бы был другой разговор ... что сами пытались сделать по части этой непростой задачи?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Anatol/T6kDR/ - третий пример.

Comment: через toggleClass элемент поворачивается мгновенно.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужен, как уже было написано, toggleClass и свойство transition в css.

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#elem').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('transform');
    });
});
```

**css**

```
#elem {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#elem.transform {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h0ruhx4h/